# How to find accuracy of model from hdf5 generated from keras?

Tags: image, deep-learning, keras, hdf5

I have trained a CNN model using keras and I saved its weight in HDF5 file.

Now I want to see accuracy of my model, how can I find it?

and how can I predict unlabled data using HDF5 ? Is it possible using h5 file?

Thanks

Comment: You mean - accuracy after training? And have you saved your model using `model.save()`?

Comment: Yes.. I saved as "model_weights.h5" .. now how can I access accuracy from this file?

Answer (score 0):

Create your model and compile it using model.compile.Then, you can load the weight with :

model.load_weights('my_model_weights.h5')

then you can use model.evaluate on your testing set. Find more info on model.evaluate here : [Model API](https://keras.io/models/model/)